# How can I follow a user (mobile phone) and draw a path on a map using leafletjs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, leaflet

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map_init = L.map('map', {
            center: [9.0820, 8.6753],
            zoom: 8
        });
        var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map_init);
        L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map_init);
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
            console.log("Your browser doesn't support geolocation feature!")
        } else {
            setInterval(() => {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition)
            }, 500);
        };
        var marker, circle, lat, long, accuracy;

        function getPosition(position) {
            // console.log(position)
            lat = position.coords.latitude
            long = position.coords.longitude
            accuracy = position.coords.accuracy

            if (marker) {
                map_init.removeLayer(marker)
            }

            if (circle) {
                map_init.removeLayer(circle)
            }

            marker = L.marker([lat, long])
            circle = L.circle([lat, long], { radius: accuracy })

            var featureGroup = L.featureGroup([marker, circle]).addTo(map_init)

            map_init.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds())

            console.log("Your coordinate is: Lat: " + lat + " Long: " + long + " Accuracy: " + accuracy)
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It shows my current position and will update when I move, however I want to draw the path taken on the map. I have not found any examples of this. Most routing plugins seem to require and endpoint to draw a path (ie: OSRM).

After drawing a path the user will be able to click "stop tracking" button and then save this path to mongodb so they can look at it later. Not sure how to do that either.

https://jsfiddle.net/chovy/s4k20gwz/2/

Comment: Hey, this might be helpful [Drawing polyline in leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/374104/178607)

Comment: sort of but not realy. i get the examples but how do I apply to my code?

Comment: "It shows my current position and will update when I move" ... Save the lat,lng to vars of what was last was. Then on "changes" OR boolean of either current lat,lng, draw the line between last and current, then make the last coords the current.

Comment: Can you please share this code is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), I think I can help you better that way

Comment: I couldn't get codesandbox working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chovy/s4k20gwz/2/

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you are asking to track the path of the user as they move?

One option could be to **add each new marker to a list as the positions are recorded rather than deleting the old marker**

Aka every time  getPosition() is called, generate a new marker and append it to a list rather than deleting the old one when a new position is made.

This should then keep the previous markers on the map and track the path of the user as they move.

```
 var trackingPath = [] 

        function getPosition(position) {
            // console.log(position)
            lat = position.coords.latitude
            long = position.coords.longitude
            accuracy = position.coords.accuracy

            marker = L.marker([lat, long])
            circle = L.circle([lat, long], { radius: accuracy })

            var featureGroup = L.featureGroup([marker, circle]).addTo(map_init)

            map_init.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds())

            trackingPath.push([marker, circle])
       
             console.log("Your coordinate is: Lat: " + lat + " 
             Long: " + long + " Accuracy: " + accuracy)
        }
```

Comment: Testing this out. How do I get rid of the giant blue dot? i just want a path that is easy to see.

Comment: I removed circle and now I have multiple markers. Is it possible to get a line?